# How to store a huge amount of static data for a SPA in javascript array?

Tags: javascript, performance

I have been working on a Single Page Application that incorporates some part of the unihan.txt data from unicode.org. It shows all the Chinese radicals (both simplified and traditional) and clicking on them shows all the Chinese characters with this radical in groups depending on their stroke count. It is also possible to do a reverse look up, if you type in a Chinese character, it will show the radical number and the stroke count.

The way I got it to work was to import the unihan data in a database and with a script convert some of the data into two javascript files:

data_codep.js (cp[codepoint]=[radical,strokes];)

```
var cp = new Array();

cp[13312]=[10,4];
cp[13313]=[10,5];
cp[13314]=[10,5];
cp[13315]=[20,2];
cp[13316]=[20,2];
cp[13317]=[40,1];
cp[13318]=[40,5];
cp[13319]=[50,2];
cp[13320]=[50,2];
cp[13321]=[50,2];
cp[13322]=[50,3];
cp[13323]=[50,3];
cp[13324]=[50,4];
cp[13325]=[50,4];
cp[13326]=[50,4];
cp[13327]=[50,4];
cp[13328]=[50,5];
[...]
(75622 lines, 1.55Mb)
```

data_radical_stroke.js (uh[radical][strokes]=[codepoint,...];)

```
var uh = new Array();  
uh[10]=new Array();
uh[10][0]=[19968];
uh[10][1]=[19969,19970,19971,19972,19973,19974,131072,131073,131074];
uh[10][2]=[19975,19976,19977,19978,19979,19980,20112,21316,131075,131076,131077,131078,173824,173825,177984];
uh[10][3]=[19981,19982,19983,19984,19985,19986,19987,19991,63847,131079,131080,131081,131082,131083,131084,173826];
uh[10][4]=[13312,19988,19989,19990,19992,19993,19994,19995,19996,19997,131085,131086,131087,131088,131089,131090,131091,131092,131093,131094,131095];
uh[10][5]=[13313,13314,19998,19999,20000,20001,20002,131096,131097,131098,131100,131102,131103,131104,177985];
uh[10][6]=[20003,20004,20005,20029,131105,131106,131107,131108,131110,131111,131112,131114,131115,177986,194560];
uh[10][7]=[20006,20007,64112,131116,131117,131118,131120,131121,131122,131123,131124,173827];
uh[10][8]=[131125,131126,131128,131130,131131,173828];
uh[10][9]=[131133,131134,131135,131136,133410,173829];
uh[10][10]=[131137,131138,131139,131140,131141,173830];
uh[10][11]=[131142,131143,131144,131146,131147];
uh[10][12]=[131148,131149];
uh[10][13]=[131150,131151,131152,131153,131154,177987];
uh[10][14]=[131155,131156];
uh[10][15]=[131157,131159,131160,131161,131162,131163,131165,150735,173831];
uh[10][16]=[131158];
uh[10][17]=[131167];
uh[10][19]=[131168];

uh[20]=new Array();
uh[20][0]=[20008];
uh[20][1]=[20009,131169,131170];
[...]
(4676 lines, 564 kB)
```

I just wanted to see if this works, and it does work with browsers like Chrome and IE on my average desktop PC. data_codep.js loads in appr. 1.15 sec. and data_radical_stroke.js in appr. 375 msec. And the page is loaded and executed in appr. 1.85 sec. It surprised me a bit. Even presenting data is almost immediate.

But, probably not a surprise, it crashed Safari on an iPad1.

Now I know that this may be a bit to much to ask from a browser. Fetching the data from the server when it is needed is obviously a more efficient mechanism. (Especially with a back-end like, for instance, Node.js) Still i am curious whether this can be achieved in a better, more efficient way.

I thought about loading in a string and cutting it up with a regular expression and then .push each piece of data into an array, but with this amount of data, would that not take a very long time? I think the same would be true for converting it into a json file and then parse it.

How can this be done with a smaller footprint?

(note: radicals have a 0 appended when they have a traditional shape and a 1 when they have a simplified shape)

Answer (score 0):

When loading data into a SPA, I use [the best practice recommended by the Backbone documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-bootstrap) and bootstrap the data into the page when it loads, rather than incurring a large network call, which is going to be slower when you want the data later on. You might also consider caching the data into the local storage mechanism (if it doesn't change often), which is doable since the size of the two files is overall pretty small.

In my opinion, get the data to the point where all your have to do is something like this in your SPA:

```
<script>var characterData = JSON.parse(<?php json_encode($data); ?>);</script>
```

Keep HTTP requests minimized up-front while loading as much data as you can into the page. `JSON.parse` is a native method (back to IE8, I think), and [it's pretty fast](http://jsperf.com/json-parse-vs-eval/3). Of course, I recommend benchmarking it for your own data load.